# How to remove path prefix when checking out remote branches with git bash?

Tags: git, bash

This is a nice command to checkout all remote branches

```
for remote in `git branch -r `; do git checkout -b $remote remotes/$remote; done
```

If my structure is like this however:

```
/refs
 |--remotes
    |--remote1/
       |--branch1
       |--branch2
    |--remote2/
       |--branch1
       |--branch2
```

how can I let the above command execute only on remotes/remote1?

Or put differently: If I have multiple remotes, how can I copy all branches of a specific remote to local branches but remove the remote's prefix? I.e. remote1/branch1 should end up as local branch /branch1 in my working copy, NOT /remote1/branch1

Comment: This is better-off without `bash`, remove the tag!

Comment: Read the description for the [tag:checkout] tag: "Checkout is the process of finishing a transaction after using a shopping application for some time."

Comment: @Inian Why would the bash tag be wrong? This question is about how to pre/postprocess git's output which more than likely can be solved with various bash commands. I think you could even abstract away the fact that the ouput came from git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really just a simple `grep`:

```
for remote in $(git branch -r | grep ^remote1/)
do
  git checkout -b $remote remotes/$remote
done
```

Piping the output of `git branch -r` through `grep ^remote1/` means that only branches matching the `^remote1/` regex will be spit out. (Be forewarned that having spaces in your branch names will cause trouble here.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to make local branches,

```
git push . refs/remotes/remote1/*:refs/heads/*
```